# Detect memory thrashing in Windows

Tags: .net, windows, memory

I'm developing an application that performs both CPU and memory intensive calculations. One issue that can occur is that we run too many calculation tasks in parallel, causing the machine to use too much memory and everything to grind to a halt. The solution is simple: run less tasks in parallel. However windows provides no warning that there is too much memory pressure, and sometimes our users are not aware they're running too many tasks. We'd like to show a warning from the application to help our users.

Question 1: is it a good idea to provide such a warning, or is there something conceptually wrong with this?

Question 2: what would be a good way to detect that memory shortage is causing poor performance? I'm considering simply seeing what percentage of physical memory is still free, and to issue a warning when that percentage gets very low. However this seems somewhat arbitrary and liable to false positives.

Are there other ways to see whether an application or windows is doing a lot of memory swapping, or maybe spending a lot of time in garbage collection? I'm running a .NET application on Windows.

Comment: It is *impossible* for a user to not notice when a machine starts thrashing.  It's not like you can't see it, use System.Management to monitor Win32Process, "Page faults/sec".  But false alarms is a serious risk.  Tends to be a sloppy programming problem, but the fix is entirely too cheap to spend much time on it.  The amount of RAM your program needs must be part of the stated minimum system requirements and needs to be verified by your installer.

Comment: When calculating, our users will generally not be using the machine, but just be waiting for a calculation to finish, so they might not notice any thrashing. Also our application does not require a predetermined amount of RAM. It's also quite hard to determine how much RAM a calculation will need before actually running it. I will look into monitoring "Page faults/sec" though.

Comment: Hyma, don't do this.  Telling the user something that is already blatantly obvious to him is not a useful feature.  This is the kind of stuff that project disasters are made of, a program that cannot complete the task it is suppose to perform in the allotted time is not a usable program.  Put your energy where it belongs, there always is a correlation between dataset size and memory usage.  If you don't know it yet then you have to take the time to measure it.

Comment: Hans: Your answer is not understandable. "there always is a correlation between dataset size and memory usage." What exactly do you want to tell us with this?

Answer (score 0):

If a number of threads you use for calculation exceeds the number of CPU cores (say N) you already slows downs the calculation because OS spending time to switching thread contexts but only N threads are working at the same time. You need somehow limit a number of threads doing massive calculations by N or N - 1 (1 thread is for GUI main thread).

What about a memory you can check the amount of free memory before a new calculation routine starts and delay it if there is no enough memory - for example put such task into a queue.